# WCF Service returning error 405 for GET requests but not POST requests

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I see a lot of instances of this question around, but I don't see any answers that seem to fit my use case at all so I figure I'll ask it again with my own details.

I have a simple RESTful WCF service to which I can POST without issue, but which returns a 405 error when I try to do GET requests.

The main difference between my situation and the solutions I see are as follows

- I am NOT using ASP.NET, this is a standalone C# app, there is no web.config
- I am NOT running this from IIS, it is just an exe

Here is how I am creating and starting my WCF service:

```
mHTTPserver = new WebServiceHost(new FileProcessService(), new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", httpIp, httpPort)));
ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = mHTTPserver.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
sdb.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;
ServiceEndpoint ep = mHTTPserver.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFileProcessService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
mHTTPserver.Open();
```

This is the service interface that I use:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileProcessService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ProcessFile?s={session}&file={fileName}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream ProcessFile(int session, string fileName);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "status", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ServerStatus GetStatus();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "clients", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<MapAtDeskClient> GetClients();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "work", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<WorkItem> GetWorkItems();
}
```

The return objects all have data contracts.

Is there some piece of configuration that I'm missing? Could it be some security setting on the host?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you may want to try hosting the service as follows:

```
mHTTPserver = new WebServiceHost(new FileProcessService(), new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", httpIp, httpPort)));
mHTTPserver.Open();
```

Essentially the same host instantiation you have, except you let the WebServiceHost automatically generate the endpoint rather than manually configuring.

According to MSDN, "If WebServiceHost finds no endpoints in the service description, it automatically creates a default endpoint at the service's base address for HTTP and HTTPS base addresses. It does not create an endpoint automatically if the user has configured an endpoint explicitly at the base address."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost(v=vs.110).aspx